# writing float to a file in java in machine independent manner so that it can be used by code in some other language

Tags: java

When I write to a file in java using data output stream, the float value contains extra characters :

```
DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
String output ="This part has no extra characters" 
writer.writeBytes(output);
writer.writeFloat(entry.getValue().floatValue());
writer.writeBytes("Neither does this. Only the float has extra characters which are     visible in vim and not visible when I cat the file\n");
```

How do I remove the extra characters from the float value ?

Comment: What do you mean by "extra characters"? `DataOutputStream` output is intended to be consumed later by a `DataInputStream` and contains exactly what is needed for this to happen.  If you don't like the encoding produced by `DataOutputStream` then you should define your own method for encoding data and use a regular `OutputStream` subclass.

Comment: There are overhead bytes that won't be removed.

Comment: There are no 'extra characters'. There are four bytes containing the binary representation of the float in standard IEEE 754 format. Your question is really about how to *read* that data in another, unspecified language, and therefore cannot be answered in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I remove the extra characters from the float value ?

You don't. You seem to misunderstand the purpose of `DataOutputStream.writeFloat()` et al.

`DataOutputStream` is meant for writing Java primitives (int, float etc.) to a file, in order to read them back later. It is *not* meant for producing output readable by humans.

So it does not make sense to view the output using `cat` or `vim`, which are meant for human-readable text.

Comment: I understand your point. However, I want this data to be sent to some other code which is not written in Java. So, it doesnt understand the output of DataOutputStream. To better frame my question, how can I write the float so that some other code can understand it and process it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You've already done it, using exactly the correct Java API. The real question here is how to *read* it with your other code in your unstated other language.

Comment: @user2418812: Ok, so *that* is your real question. Please edit that information into your question, and add relevant information (e.g. what language the "other code" is written in). Then ask a moderator to reopen it (by flagging it).